# When does the replication from primary to secondary happen?

Tags: mongodb

I have setup a 3 node replica set.

Writing to primary node works but when I read with `readPreference=secondary;` I get values as null.

When I open the local node with robomongo I see that the collection does not exist. So it has not been replicated?

I am not sure when it gets replicated or am I missing something?

**Update**

I have used the following URI

`mongodb://DNS1,DNS2,DNS3/?readPreference=secondary&w=0`

Comment: Not really enough information here to determine what your problem is, or if indeed it is a programming question suitable for this forum. Some reading on [Write Concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) may be suggested before then updating your question with any relevant information.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have update the question so I am trying to connect to the DB using the WriteConcern 0; so it shoudl immediately replicate? or how can I see that whether primary has replicated to secondary?

Sorry I am very new to MongoDB world :(

Comment: Then your question is of-topic for here as it is **server** related. Try [server fault](http://serverfault.com/), another stack exchange site for replication configuration questions.

Comment: why do u suspect its a server fault?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ It's a website. That's why it was a **link** not a statement. You **can't** ask questions like this here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ok my apologies. I will post it there. Thank you.